# Image to text with same format - MLkit firebase

Tags: java, android, ocr, firebase-mlkit

I'm developing an app to extract the text from Nutrition fact. By using MLkit firebase I achieve that, but I have one problem that the text doesn't show in the same format as in the image. Here is my code for text recognition.

```
            // ----TextRecognizer START ---


            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) mPreview.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();



            final FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);
            FirebaseVisionCloudTextRecognizerOptions options = new FirebaseVisionCloudTextRecognizerOptions.Builder()
                    .setLanguageHints(Arrays.asList("en", "ar"))
                    .build();
            // [END set_detector_options_cloud]

            // [START get_detector_cloud]
            // Or, to change the default settings:
               FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                      .getCloudTextRecognizer(options);
            // [END get_detector_cloud]

            // [START run_detector_cloud]

            Task<FirebaseVisionText> result2 = detector.processImage(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText result) {
                            // Task completed successfully
                            // [START_EXCLUDE]
                            // [START get_text_cloud]
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            for (FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock block : result.getTextBlocks()) {
                                if (result.getTextBlocks().size() == 0){
                                    mResultEt.setText("NO Text Found");
                                }else {
                                    Rect boundingBox = block.getBoundingBox();
                                    Point[] cornerPoints = block.getCornerPoints();
                                    String text = block.getText();

                                    for (FirebaseVisionText.Line line: block.getLines()) {
                                        sb.append(line.getText());
                                        sb.append("\n");
                                        for (FirebaseVisionText.Element element: line.getElements()) {

                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                            mResultEt.setText(sb);


                            // [END get_text_cloud]
                            // [END_EXCLUDE]
```

[This is an image I want to extract the text from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN9Y5.jpg) 
 [this is the result but the format not as the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PlKs.jpg)

I tried different solutions by adding a new line or tab but it's the same.

By the way, I want to use the numbers in the image to do some calculations.

If anyone can help me with it, I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

ML Kit does not automatically detect the layout for now. But each detected text has its own coordinates. One solution is to use the [text coordinates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/text/FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock#getBoundingBox()) to detect decide the layout manually.

Say the 'Serving Size' and '1 Can' has the similar X-axle, then you may want to group them together.